# Gmail how to switch on content type html

Tags: html, gmail, content-type

I have an html table like

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

and I need to send it via gmail. How to switch on the content type from plain text to html in Gmail to get the html view instead of text

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a programming related question. It would be better suited to https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour or https://superuser.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. The chrome extention ***HTML Inserter for Gmail*** should be added to Chrome and it gives the functionality to insert html (extention icon is located in formatter tools)